# T-SQL get substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I am looking to get an order number from a column named KEY_Ref, this ref column have various contents, but some rows look like this

```
LINE_NO=15^ORDER_NO=176572^RELEASE_NO=1^
```

Now I am interested in getting the value for ORDER_NO (176572 in this case)

How would I (In SQL Server) go about getting this (Or other) value from the main string

The logic is always
key1=value1^key2=value2^key3=value3^

Comment: Pity you, those values should be in separate columns.

Comment: I could not agree more, alas this is my reality :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, s.orderno
from t outer apply
     (select stuff(s.value, 1, 9, '') as orderno
      from string_split(t.key_ref, '^') s
      where s.value like 'ORDER_NO=%'
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=517e47e878d03936040b479ad698ffef) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to be a bit lengthy answer however if your SQL server version doesn't support string_split function you may use this.

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'LINE_NO=15^ORDER_NO=176572^RELEASE_NO=1^'

declare @substr1 varchar(50) = substring(@str,charindex('^',@str)+1,len(@str))


declare @substr2 varchar(50) = substring(@substr1,charindex('=',@substr1)+1,charindex('^',@substr1)-charindex('=',@substr1)-1)

select @substr2 as 'order number'
```

the final variable will produce the desired value and you must merge the above queries to a single query that can fetch the value from the table in a single select statement.

this will work only if the pattern doesn't deviate from the one you've mentioned.